# Increase Scroll view height in middle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have a scroll view and one Plus button is there to add the extra text fields under the add button.
Please check the screenshot below for reference.

[image]

Comment: while button click you need to create the uitextfield ,set constraints for that.

Comment: use visual constraints its easy for you.

Comment: No did every thing by programatically i didnot use the autolayouts

Comment: ok do it via programatically ,visual constraints is available.

Comment: for that i want to add Autolayouts?

Comment: are you developing app for universal (or) some other selected device .

Comment: Is there any other way without using the Visual constraints

Comment: developing for Universal but i am managing programatically by taking the view size for outlets

Comment: ok now a case you need to set visual constraints rather than its complicated .

Comment: wait i will try to help you.

Comment: ok,Please help me in this

Comment: You can take one base view for each group of text fields and set the constarints on that base view linked with the bottom label. On each plus create a dynamic Text Field and add it to the base view once you add the Text Field to the base view increase the height constraint of the base view which will automatically shift the data(labels, etc.) below this base view.

Comment: @Milan is it not possible without autolayouts,every thing i did programtically,if i go for constraints it will give the headache

Comment: Well auto layout is the preferred way of doing this, but it can be done without that as well. The logic would be same, all you need to do is whatever the constraints will do automatically you have to do that programmatically. That means you have to group the sectional data along with label in several base views and then once you add the fields to it you have to change the height of that particular base view and the Y value of all the base views below it. Its all about simple mathematics.

Comment: @Milan  its confusing me.i need to add the multiple base views,and have to show outlets on that,right?.

Comment: if you support only iOS 9 you can use UIScrollView with UIStackView, you can also use UITableView with insertrowsatindexpaths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)Textfield:(id)sender
{  
  i++;//global declaration int

  UITextField *textfield=[[UITextField alloc]init];
  textfield.tag=i;
  NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = {@"give-textfield-name here":self.textfield};
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[give-textfield-name]-10-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
    [self.textfield addConstraints:constraints];

}
```

Visual constraints example:

```
V:|-10-[give-textfield-name]-10-|
```

> V means vertical constraints
>
> | viewcontroller left margin &right margin
>
> 10 giving space from left margin .

[image]

And this is very basic thing of VisualConstraints ,you need to develop it more.

And one more thing you need to update the scrollviewcontent size after adding each textfield.

set the viewcontroller as freedom height and width.[update this also]

Hope it will help to start you program.

this is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html) for visual constraints.

this is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/UnderstandingAutolayout.html) for autolayout.

Comment: its seems will work, can you give me some more explanation.means i never tried the auto layout programatically

Comment: @user4815082 yes you need to switch to adaptivelayout ,it will reduce you time and you can work easily.

Comment: @user4815082 i was updated my answer you can refer the link.

Comment: @user4815082 for it takes one day to understand autolayout and visual constraints ,but after still i am learning ,it is very easiest one.

Comment: @thank you kishore,it seems there is no other way excepts contraints.i thought any function may there for increase the scroll view height at some point.if you find any thing like what i said please let me know.i am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create textfields on clicking the plus button and add tags to textfields for fetching data from it.

```
   let objForTextfield = UITextField()
        objForTextfield.frame = CGRectMake(0, (scrollView.frame.origin.y + scrollView.frame.size.height ), 100, 100)
        self.view.addSubview(objForTextfield)
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.subviews.last?.frame.origin.y)!+(scrollView.subviews.last?.frame.size.height)!
```

Comment: you did not understand my Question.i want to add the textfields  in between the subviews on clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need to group this view into three `uiviews.`

1. `first` one contain the two `text field` parts you want to show on `button`click

   2.`Second`one  contain upper part of that `text fields`

   3.`Third`one contain lower part of that `text fields`

Then set`height constraint`for `first view` and `vertical spacing` bwn

`First -Second` and `second - third`.

At first time the `height constraint` must be zero for the `first view`

And `priority of vertical spacing` of `second - third` greater than `priority` of `First -Second`.

When the `button`clicks change the`height` of`first view` and also change the `priority` of that `vertical spaces`.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and set content size of scrollview then call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]`